# Reliable way to get client IP address in CXF JAX-WS one-way method call

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws, cxf

I'm using following code to get client IP address for a JAX-WS one-way method call:

```
protected HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
    MessageContext ctx = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    return (HttpServletRequest) ctx.get( MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST );
}

protected synchronized String getClientIp() {
    String clientIp = "";
    HttpServletRequest request = getServletRequest();
    if ( request != null ) {
        clientIp = request.getRemoteAddr();

        // Handle proxy
        String header = request.getHeader( "x-forwarded-for" );
        if( header != null && !header.isEmpty() ) {
            clientIp = header.split( "," )[0];
        }
    }
    return clientIp;
}
```

When multiple clients connect in, the IP address retrieved for a request is occasionally an incorrect cached value from an earlier request. What is a reliable way to get the one-way call originator's IP address?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can use the follow code snippet to finding the client IP

```
Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is to establish a web-service connection back then perhaps [WS-Addressing](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-21-ea2/docs/why-wsaddressing.html) may be helpful.

Alternative addressing schemes aside,
`HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr` in combination with the `getHeader` alternative IP address are spec'd to be correct.
If they're not then there's not much recourse
(yea, I can imagine various contortions, but the principle remains).

So, do you have the latest/greatest stable release of your platform?  It does sound more like a problem with your platform - of which you haven't provided any details.

Comment: I'll look through WS-Addressing if it can help. 
I'm using cxf-2.5.2 running on tomcat-6.0.35.