# PhaseInterceptorChain and HttpServletRequest lead to AbstractEndpointFactory ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, maven, servlets, jax-ws, cxf

I need the ability to [reliably get client IP address in CXF JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521352/1864054) and so I added the following code to my web service:

```
Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
request.getRemoteAddr();
```

In order for the build to complete successfully, I had to add the following imports:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination;
```

And add the following dependencies to my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency> <!-- PhaseInterceptorChain & Message -->
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- HttpServletRequest -->
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <!-- scope>provided</scope -->
    </dependency>
```

But when I try to deploy the resulting successful(!) build, Tomcat (7.0.42) throws an exception and refuses to load the war file:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
  Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: 
      Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: 
        problem with handler class file or dependent class; 
          nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/endpoint/AbstractEndpointFactory
```

...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: 
  Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] 
   for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws]: 
    problem with handler class file or dependent class; 
     nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/endpoint/AbstractEndpointFactory
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractEndpointFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
```

Apparently, something is missing from my `pom.xml` that provides the necessary module at runtime. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved. For the benefit of all I am providing the root cause of the problem and the solution:

The problem was in this line:

```
   <version>2.4.0</version>
```

That is, `cxf-api` artifact's version did not match the CXF version throughout the project (and the pom.xml).

All I had to do to solve the problem was to change that line to:

```
<version>${cxf.version}</version>
```

Where `cxf.version` was defined earlier as `2.7.1`.

Conclusion: CXF dependencies/packages/plugins versions must match throughout the pom.xml (or else you will get some "red herrings").